# How can I add a number and string in a variable on Progress4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

How can I add a number and string into a character variable on Progress4GL
like the following (it's just an example to show the idea).

```
a = 'Code'
b = 1

c = a+b
```

So `c`'s value is "Code1"

How can I do it on progress4GL?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `STRING()` function to convert integer into character.

With your exemple:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE a AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE b AS INTEGER    NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE c AS CHARACTER  NO-UNDO.
a = 'Code'.
b = 1.

c = a + STRING(b).
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it and it was so close to yours except I didn't set `NO-UNDO`, what does it do exactly?

Comment: You're welcome. The `NO-UNDO`, allows not memorize the variable to undo if needed.

Comment: You should use the NO-UNDO option on every variable and temp-table definition unless you need to support backing the values out on a transaction undo (rollback). Otherwise Progress will keep track of value changes during transactions that will cause extra overhead. A small performance gain but it adds up over time and volume.

Comment: @TheMadDBA Thank you so much for telling me that +1, I'm still new to progress4gl